# When rigging my grease pencil object gets stuck at a point

Tags: armature, bones, grease-pencil

[image]I want the black grease pencil line on the shoe to move with the foot. some of it moves (the part connected to the shoe) but some of it stays behind. Why? How can I just get it all to move with the foot?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7oqX.jpg)[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the GPencil object, switch to weight paint mode, select the relevant vertex group and paint the desired weights (uniformily if you want undeformed movements, or distributing weights across different vertex groups if you need bendings and deformations).

Alternatively, you can go to Edit mode and use Assign/Remove weights buttons under the vertex groups list.

[image]